# R function to find optimal ranking of objects in a data frame?

Tags: r, permutation, mathematical-optimization, combinatorics

I'm attempting to find the optimal order of a list of *n* number of products to maximize revenue.

Example:

```
Product    Position 1    Position 2    Position 3

   X       $0.38         $0.17         $0.11

   Y       $1.08         $0.71         $0.52

   Z       $0.82         $0.41         $0.26
```

A product (X,Y,Z) can only be listed once and each position (1,2,3) can only be listed once as well. For this example there are 6 possible solutions *(n=3, r=3, 3!/(3!-3!)=6)* but this should be able to apply to *n* products ranked in *r* spots

```
X1 + Y2 + Z3 = $1.35
X1 + Z2 + Y3 = $1.31
Y1 + X2 + Z3 = $1.51
Y1 + Z2 + X3 = $1.60
Z1 + X2 + Y3 = $1.51
Z1 + Y2 + X3 = $1.64
```

The final combination (Z1 + Y2 + X3) would be chosen because $1.64 provides the maximum revenue. In addition to finding the optimal revenue figure I need to know the ordered combination that was chosen so I know which products belong in which position.

I've tried functions like combn and expand.grid but those seem to combine all elements in a vector whereas I can only have one product existing in one position.

Is R a viable tool for this problem? Do I need to structure the data in a different format?

Comment: Hello fellow Graeme! I would suggest looking into using tidy data format, which you can transform your data into using packages like `tidyr`. The resulting format would have three columns: product, rank, and revenue. That should make it easier to work with

Comment: Why would group A and B be related if the products in one group are completely different from the products in the other?

Comment: @GraemeFrost I can transform the data to the format you suggested with the three columns but I'm not sure how that gets me closer to solving for the optimal ranking

Comment: @Alexis maybe I didn't word that very well. Groups A and B are not related and have a separate set of products. The issue is I have to repeat this process for 250+ groups of products so I just want to make sure the solution could easily be applied across multiple groups of data. I guess ideally I find a solution that solves this for Group A and then I could write a loop function to iterate the process across Group B, C, D, etc.

Comment: @Graham ah ok, but then I'm not sure you need to actually allocate any combination, if your revenue is simply a sum, can't you simply find the rank that maximizes each product? In your example, Rank 1 gives you the most revenue per product, so combining all Rank 1 products would maximize the total revenue.

Comment: @Alexis A product (X,Y,Z) can only be ranked once and each position (1,2,3) can only be ranked once as well. So for example if I put Product X in Position 1 then I can't list Product X again and I can't list any Position 1 data again. I would have to choose between Y2,Z3 or Z2,Y3. I'll try to reword some of my question to be more concise

Answer (score 1):

From "*but this solution should be able to apply to N products ranked in N spots*"  we know that the `number of products = number of spots = N`. This is essentially an **assignment problem**.

The mathematical model is usually stated as:

```
 min sum((i,j), c[i,j]*x[i,j])
 subject to
     sum(i, x[i,j]) = 1   for all locations j
     sum(j, x[i,j]) = 1   for all products i
     x[i,j] in {0,1}
```

This can be solved with an LP solver, or with specialized solvers. See [link](https://yetanothermathprogrammingconsultant.blogspot.com/2016/03/large-assignment-problem.html) for some (limited) performance figures. I don't think it is very easy to develop your own algorithm that finds optimal solutions and does this very quickly.

PS The sentence "*but this solution should be able to apply to N products ranked in N spots*" has been removed by the poster, which is a bit unfortunate. So the problem has changed somewhat. As the problem changes, the model may need to be updated. Instead of a balanced assignment problem, we now have an unbalanced one. Depending on whether the number of products (N) is less or greater than the number of locations (M) we need change the model a little bit. It still can be formulated as an LP/MIP, or can be cast into an assignment problem by adding dummy source or destination nodes.

Comment: Hi Erwin, this does seem like an assignment problem so thanks for getting me on the right track. I initially thought it would be N products in N spots but it's probably better stated as - if N>10 then M=10, if N<=10 then M=N. So there would only be situations where number of products (N) is greater than or equal to the number of locations (M). From what I've read it seems like your suggestion of adding dummy locations to keep it a balanced assignment problem could work. Do you think the lpSolve package in R can work to solve this problem?

Comment: From the link you can see lpsolve is slow for large instances. But it certainly works.